# Hibernate is not pulling correct values from database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

This one is a little hard to phrase.  The goal here is that you give the code a file extension, as a string, and it queries the database to see if that extension can be uploaded.  In case you're wondering why I don't just put this information in a Map, it's because I need the ability to change this without recompiling the program.

I have this Hibernate mapping (old school XML based).

```
<class name="com.everhood.FileTypeStatus" table="FILE_TYPE_FILTER">
    <property name="extension" column="extension"/>
    <property name="allowed" column="allowed"/>
</class>
```

And the object:

```
  package com.everhood;
    
    import java.io.Serializable;
    
    public class FileTypeStatus implements Serializable {
        private String extension;
        private boolean allowed;
    
        public String getExtension() {
            return extension;
        }
    
        public void setExtension(String extension) {
            this.extension = extension;
        }
    
        public boolean isAllowed() {
            return allowed;
        }
    
        public void setAllowed(boolean allowed) {
            this.allowed = allowed;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("FileTypeStatus{");
            sb.append("extension='").append(extension).append('\'');
            sb.append(", allowed=").append(allowed);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

And the code in the DAO class.

```
    @Override
    public FileTypeStatus getFileExtensionStatus(String fileExtension) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(FileTypeStatus.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("extension",fileExtension));

        FileTypeStatus result = (FileTypeStatus) crit.uniqueResult();

        return result;
      }
```

If you pass a valid file extension, such as "pdf", you it should return a FileTypeStatus object with "pdf" for the extension and "true" for the allowed field.  What I get instead is null, which means it didn't find any result at all.  If I run this query:

```
select * from file_type_filter where extension = 'pdf';
```

I get one row, like I should.

My Java code **is** passing the file extension as all lower case, so it's not a case sensitivity issue.

I had thought that using crit.uniqueResult() might have caused a problem, but crit.list() returns an empty list.  I haven't tried a lot of things, so I can't pick out what could be causing this.

Comment: The usual first step for problems like this is to turn on `show_sql` and examine the statements being generated.

Comment: It's already set.  Doesn't work for some reason.  Our code base is a real mess.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a typo in the original code.
I see an upper case and lower spelling of FILE_TYPE_FILTER

I would try changing the class to:

```
<class name="com.everhood.FileTypeStatus" table="file_type_filter">
```

Or I would try changing the column in the database table to:

```
FILE_TYPE_FILTER
```

I suggest this because you are getting results with:

```
select * from file_type_filter where extension = 'pdf';
```

And you get a Null value with:

```
<class name="com.everhood.FileTypeStatus" table="FILE_TYPE_FILTER">
```